# Slow PS4 internet speed on wired and wireless networks?

Tags: technical-issues, networking, ps4

I have a 50Mbps connection from my ISP. My laptops, Xbox360, mobile phones, etc. get around 30-40Mbps download speed. However, the PS4 only gets a mere **2-4Mbps**. I thought that there is a mistake where it should say a download speed of MBps, but no, they're actually bits. This explains the lag I've been getting in games.

I went over to `speedof.me` to test the speed on my PS4, and I still get around 2-4Mbps.

Can someone tell me why this is happening? The internet connection test says I have NAT Type 2.

Comment: The NAT shouldn't impact your speed much, but it *does* influence your multiplayer experience. NAT 1 and 2 are good; NAT 3 means there's a problem. Do you have a torrent client running on your PC on the same network as your PS4?

Comment: Nope, it's a house network. So multiple devices are connected but none have speeds less than 20-30Mbps

Comment: Yup, lets just hope this is a firmware issue and not a hardware one. I'm regrettably staring to think it might be a hardware issue though as not all consoles are suffering the same issue. I hope Sony does the right thing and address this before it gets out of hand. Xbox is already creeping up in numbers and this could really hurt Sony if this becomes too wide spread.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt you're able to fix it. I (and many others, after a quick google search) have exactly the same problem and I believe that it's due to crappy firmware (jesus, I hope it's not a hardware issue).

Hopefully it will be fixed in some patch down the line. There are so many bugs that, as a professional software developer, I would have NEVER let this release.